# Angular - getting an error when using named outlet: "Cannot match any routes" while navigate from canActivate guard

Tags: angular

In my app I navigate to a login form from a `CanActivate` guard.

It wirks fine when use just one `router-outlet`.

But when try to use `named router-outlet` to show in it the login component I get an error:

> "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'".

How to fix it?

Here is the related code from my app:

**app.component.html :**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts :**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'popup', },

  { path: '', component: MainComponent,
    canActivate : [AuthGuardService],
  },
];
```

**auth-guard.service.ts :**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loginService
               .isAuthorised()
               .map(res => {
                  ...
                }).catch((err) => {
                  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this:

`this.router.navigate(['/', {outlets: {popup:'login')}]);`

Comment: Now the error is: 
`http://localhost:3000/null` - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
Why "/null" ??

Comment: It looks like this problem is solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: You save my life! Thanks ‍♀️